# Dynamic Javascript Form not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need solutions for submit a form who is charge and create dynamic, to send info to proceder.php via ajax.

First, you must click in the botton "Nuevo Concepto", and then you must click in "Editar" in the row that now add. Then, appear the form does not work correctly submit appears

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#cargardatos").on('click', function() 
            {
                var fragment = "<tr data-id='0'><td>Arandano</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td><span class='editar' onclick='transformarEnEditable(this)'>Edit</span></td></tr>";
                $(".Tabla").append(fragment);
            });

            $('#userinfo').submit(function() 
            {
                var a = $(this).attr('action');
            });
        });

        function transformarEnEditable(nodo)
        {
            var nodoTd = nodo.parentNode; //Nodo TD
            var nodoTr = nodoTd.parentNode; //Nodo TR
            var dataid = $(nodoTr).attr("data-id");
            var nodosEnTr = nodoTr.getElementsByTagName('td');

            var concepto = nodosEnTr[0].textContent;
            var precio = nodosEnTr[1].textContent;
            var cantidad = nodosEnTr[2].textContent;
            var total = nodosEnTr[3].textContent;

            var nuevoCodigoHtml = "<form name='userinfo' id='userinfo' action='envio.php'><p>Nombre: <input type='text' name='nombre'/></p><p>Precio: <input type='text' name='precio'/></p><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Cerrar</button><input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' name='SubmitButton'></form>";
            nodoTr.innerHTML = nuevoCodigoHtml;
        }

        function submitForm()
        {
            document.theForm.submit();
        }
    </script>
   </head>

    <body>      
    <table class="tabla">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Concepto</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Opciones<button id="cargardatos" class="btn btn-success">Nuevo Concepto</button></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <form action="proceder.php" method="post" onreset="anular()">
                <td><input type="text" name="concepto" value="" size="10"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="precio" value="" size="5"</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="cantidad" value="" size="5"</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="total" value="" size="5"</td>
                <td><input class="boton" name="submit" type="submit" value="Aceptar"> <input class="boton" type="reset" value="Cancelar"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

  </body>

   </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the jQuery AJAX documentation for more info: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

If you want to use AJAX after submitting the edit form, you would add something like this after inserting the form in `transformarEnEditable`.

```
$("#userinfo").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "envio.php",
        data: {
            nombre: $("#userinfo input[name='nombre']").val(),
            precio: $("#userinfo input[name='precio']").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // Do something with the data returned from envio.php.
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            // Handle error.
        }
    });
});
```

Another issue I see is that you originally have the event listener `$("#userinfo").submit(...)` before the `#userinfo` form is inserted. That `submit()` will only work on elements that already exist at the time the listener is created.

If you want to keep the listener there instead of inside the `transformarEnEditable` function, you'd want to use `on()` (http://api.jquery.com/on/). Note the usage with delegated events where the descendant elements are added later. You can use a more specific parent selector, but here I will use `body` for the sake of example:

```
$("body").on("submit", "#userinfo", function (event) { ... });
```

Comment: Thank you very much , it worked anyway! The problem is when you load the dynamic form to edit

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you had wanted to solve. Are you saying you can't get the right behavior when you submit that dynamic form? I have updated my answer to what I think you're asking about.

Comment: Edited again after observing your usage of `submit()`.

Comment: I post the actually code in [link]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342276/dynamic-form-javascript-not-working)